# How to drag and drop a marker pin in the MAUI Maps?

Tags: maui, mobile-development

How we can drag a pin in MAUI Map and drop into another position? When dropping, need to get the dropped location details(latitude and longitude).
Saw the documentation about DragGestureRecognizer and DropGestureRecognizer.
But when we drop a pin, need to get the location detail. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you can refer to the [Maui.GoogleMaps](https://github.com/themronion/Maui.GoogleMaps).

You can use `PinDragEventArgs` from above Nuget.

```
namespace Maui.GoogleMaps
{
    public sealed class PinDragEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public Pin Pin
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        internal PinDragEventArgs(Pin pin)
        {
            this.Pin = pin;
        }
    }
}
```

And we can use the three `EventHandler`s  from class `Map`.

```
namespace Maui.GoogleMaps
{
    public class Map : View, IMap, IEnumerable<Pin>
    {  
        public event EventHandler<PinDragEventArgs> PinDragStart;
        public event EventHandler<PinDragEventArgs> PinDragEnd;
        public event EventHandler<PinDragEventArgs> PinDragging;

      // other code
    }
}
```

So, we can trigger the three EventHandler as follows:

```
        map.PinDragStart += (_, e) => labelDragStatus.Text = $"DragStart - {PrintPin(e.Pin)}";
        map.PinDragging += (_, e) => labelDragStatus.Text = $"Dragging - {PrintPin(e.Pin)}";
        map.PinDragEnd += (_, e) => labelDragStatus.Text = $"DragEnd - {PrintPin(e.Pin)}";
```

Here, we can get the relative position information from the `e.Pin`,including the `Latitude` and `Longtitude`.

[image]

**Note:**

You can refer to the sample page : [CustomPinsPage.xaml.cs](https://github.com/themronion/Maui.GoogleMaps/blob/maui/sample/MauiGoogleMapSample/CustomPinsPage.xaml.cs)  from the sample [here](https://github.com/themronion/Maui.GoogleMaps/tree/maui/sample).

Comment: Hi @Jessie, thank you for the prompt response. I will try this and let you know. Thanks again.